# How can I use the tagged_with query in acts_as_taggable_on as a filter in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable-on

How can I add a filter on my Article model in Active Admin, that will display checkboxes for all available tags (or a simple input string) and act as the `tagged_with(tags)` method available with acts_as_taggable_on?

I've seen this posted before:

`filter :taggings_tag_name, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Article.tag_counts.map { |t| t.name} }`

But it uses an IN query, much like the `tagged_with(tags, :any => true)` method, which is **not** what I want.

Answer (score 2):

What you may want to do is create a custom search method and use it from the filter.

ActiveAdmin uses [meta_search](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search), so you can create a scope to refine your search and use its search_methods method.

Here's a proposal for a solution:

```
class Article

  scope :custom_tags_equals, ->( tags ) do
    tagged_with tags
  end

  search_methods :custom_tags_equals
end

ActiveAdmin.register Article do
# ...
filter :custom_tags_equals, :as => :select, 
  :collection => proc { Article.tag_counts.map{ | tag | tag.name } },
  :input_html => { :multiple => true }
# ...
end
```

Comment: How to do it with ransacker?